Chrony client is always preferring ubuntu ntp pool to local ntp server
I have a chrony NTP client where a local chrony NTP server which is present in the same LAN is configured as the preferred server. For resiliency, I have added the Ubuntu NTP pool as a fallback server. I have used the prefer directive to give priority to the local time server.
When I run the client where only the local time server is configured, it is syncing with the local time server. However, when I add the Ubuntu NTP pool as a fallback server and restart chrony client, the client is always syncing with the Ubuntu NTP pool instead of preferring the local time server.
Chrony client config


server 192.168.210.88 iburst prefer   
pool ntp.ubuntu.com iburst maxsources 4

keyfile /etc/chrony/chrony.keys

driftfile /var/lib/chrony/chrony.drift


logdir /var/log/chrony

log measurements statistics tracking 

maxupdateskew 100.0

rtcsync

makestep 1 3

chrony server config
confdir /etc/chrony/conf.d

pool ntp.ubuntu.com        iburst maxsources 4
pool 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst maxsources 1
pool 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst maxsources 1
pool 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst maxsources 2

allow 0.0.0.0/0

local stratum 1

sourcedir /run/chrony-dhcp

sourcedir /etc/chrony/sources.d

keyfile /etc/chrony/chrony.keys

driftfile /var/lib/chrony/chrony.drift

ntsdumpdir /var/lib/chrony

log tracking measurements statistics


logdir /var/log/chrony

maxupdateskew 100.0

rtcsync

makestep 1 3

leapsectz right/UTC

Note: For simplicity, I have removed the comments from the config file.
You can see that I have assigned a stratum of 1 to the server to increase its priority. I thought that the stratum of servers in the Ubuntu NTP pool might be lesser than that of the local server. But it didn't solve the issue.
I'm a beginner in time servers and NTP. Apart from troubleshooting this specific issue, I happily welcome suggestions on setting up a local time server for a LAN; a better way to do it.
Thank you for your time :)
